# Good examples of a site search with relevance across multiple tables (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, search, relevance

I am trying to build a site-wide search with relevance, the site has around 5 tables that needs to be searched could anyone provide some assistance (or links) that will help to achieve this? (Never done this before and I don't really want to use a google plugin that will show the google image all over it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) search its very powerfull and supports multiple kinds of data from multiple places.

Comment: +1 Zend Framework's Lucene-component: Zend_Search_Lucene (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.lucene.intro.html) might be a good start.

Comment: @mahok I love Zend_Lucene but since the guy seems to not be using zf I prefered not to suggest it.

Comment: I only mentioned it, because the question was tagged with php and thus I thought it might be more accessible, than Java.

Comment: Unfortunately I am actually using Codeigniter (v2) rather than Zend :(

Comment: See guys? Now he thinks lucene is a zend thing. ITS NOT.